# Pass to the next image everyday

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm developing a small app in AS3. 
Everyday, you can see a new image.

I've got all my image on a server.

Here is my code for the moment :

```
var imageLoader:Loader = new Loader();

var days:Array = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday"];
var my_date:Date = new Date();
trace(days[my_date.day]);
startBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, LoadImage, false, 0, true);

function LoadImage(event:MouseEvent):void{
    var image:URLRequest = new URLRequest ("http://www.blabla.com/images/12.jpg");
        imageLoader.load(image);
        addChild (imageLoader);
}
```

Is it possible to tell the code the go the next image (13.jpg) the next day ? and everyday like that (next day = 14.jpg , next day = 15.jpg....ect).

Do you know a way to do that ?

Thank you very much for your help,

Comment: so 7 images, one for each day of the week?

Comment: Yes but for the entire year (I've got 365 images on my server)

Comment: so you want it for each day of the year? the files have a naming convention counting from 1..365? (maybe 366 is prudent)

Comment: Yes. No problem for 366. My images are named like that "1.jpg","2.jpg"...etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below should do it. I grabbed the getDayOfYear function from here: [siafoo.net](http://www.siafoo.net/snippet/222)

I will post some optimizations to the function in a little while.

```
function getDayOfYear(date:Date):Number {   
    var monthLengths:Array = new Array (31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31);
    // A leap year is divisable by 4, but not by 100 unless divisable by 400.
    if (((date.getFullYear() % 4 == 0) && (date.getFullYear() % 100 != 0)) || (date.getFullYear() % 400 == 0)) {
        monthLengths[1] = 29;
    }

    var dayInYear = 0;
    // get day of year up to month
    for (var i:Number = 0; i < date.getMonth(); i++) {
    dayInYear += monthLengths[i];
    }

    // add day inside month
    dayInYear += date.getDate();

    // Start counting on 0 (optional)
    // dayInYear--;

    return dayInYear;
}


function LoadImage(event:MouseEvent):void{
  var image:URLRequest = new URLRequest ("http://www.blabla.com/images/"+getDayOfYear(new Date())+".jpg");
  imageLoader.load(image);
  addChild (imageLoader);
}
```

Comment: I've got this error : Erreur d’ouverture de l’URL 'http://www.cocogeek.fr/downloads/null.jpg'
Error #2044: IOErrorEvent non pris en charge : text=Error #2036: Le chargement n'a pas été achevé.

Comment: By the way cocogeek.fr/downloads/  = blabla.com/images/ (which was an exemple)

Comment: the link string is up to you. Just put "(getDayOfYear(my_date) as String)" where you need the number.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand. For the moment, whith the code you gave me and my "1.jpg" on the server, I've got this error :URL 'cocogeek.fr/downloads/null.jpg'; Error #2044: I don't understand why. Thanks again for your help !

Comment: try this instead:   (getDayOfYear(new Date()) as String)

Comment: Hmmm. Nope, same error Erreur d’ouverture de l’URL 'http://www.cocogeek.fr/downloads/null.jpg'
Error #2044: IOErrorEvent non pris en charge : text=Error #2036: Le chargement n'a pas été achevé.

Comment: If I put trace(getDayOfYear(new Date()) as String) I've got "null" as a response

Comment: Found the solution. It was "(getDayOfYear(new Date()))". Thank you for your help !

Comment: You could also use `(new Date()).getDay()`

Comment: Quick question though, how do I do if I want to change every week, instead of every day ?

Comment: A simple way wold be to divide getDayOfYear by 7, but the weeks might not fall on the day you want. You can divide by 7, and add the dayOfYear representing the first Sunday or Monday of the year to get it lined up to the correct day of the week.